# Why does God stress both on Sansar and Moksha

Tags: krishna, karma, moksha

In Vishnu stuti It is said to pray Sridhara before meeting one's dear in the line and says one who repeats all of his names attains Vaikuntha that is moksha

> Sridhara priya Sangame

which shows Being in Sansar can also help attain Moksha(as being in love is materialistic) but at the same time he says one has to leave all the karma bandha and one must go in the route of Krishna to attain Moksha My doubt is can one attain moksha staying in sansar or does Bhagwan want us to be in sansar and then leave everything behind and come to him after fulfilling our materialistic responsibilities?

Comment: The insight is to see everything in samsara as goddesses herself.

Comment: The can one attain moksha being in sansara

Comment: Yeah, everything we are experiencing is a form of goddesses only. One needs to achieve moksha being in samsara only. It happens when one can experience the goddesses in each and all. But, humans generally tend to perceive samsara as an entity different from her, which is untrue.

Comment: Read about [jivan mukthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jivanmukta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who  has the true quest to attain moksha,the choice over  ,one of different paths of yoga according to one's own tendencies ,as a stepping stone to embark on, is left to the individual as conveyed in the following Bhagavad Gita shloka 7.20,7.21

> yo yo yāṁ yāṁ tanuṁ bhaktaḥ śhraddhayārchitum ichchhati
> tasya tasyāchalāṁ śhraddhāṁ tām eva vidadhāmyaham

> Whatever celestial form a devotee seeks to worship with faith, I steady the faith of such a devotee in that form.

> kāmais tais tair hṛita-jñānāḥ prapadyante ’nya-devatāḥ
> taṁ taṁ niyamam āsthāya prakṛityā niyatāḥ svayā

> Those whose knowledge has been carried away by material desires surrender to the celestial gods. Following their own nature, they worship the devatās, practicing rituals meant to propitiate these celestial personalities.

Though, several schools of philosophy abiding vedic system , may hold disparate views . ( well, different ways and means of practice,) they  all coexist ,  (due to varied nature of individuals),  it is one's own choice to make an option for one's  spiritual progress,

Whatever path one chooses , supreme reality strengthens that faith.

Though, an individual being  in sansar,(overtime)  develops a natural tendency of dispassion towards all worldy sense objects, (akin to an adults dispassion for toddler toys), and yearns only for the Lord, marks  the onset of Brahmanishta.This can be seen in the life history of several revered saints of culture.

Although, Lord also graces trivarga, if it is the choice made by the devotee.

what is the possibility of attaining that level  of realization?

Bhagavad Gita 7.3  says it's a rareity to attain such a siddhi

> manuṣhyāṇāṁ sahasreṣhu kaśhchid yatati **siddhaye**
> yatatām api siddhānāṁ kaśhchin māṁ vetti tattvataḥ

> In this verse, Shree Krishna has used siddhi for perfection in the spiritual path. He says, “Only a tiny portion of the innumerable souls are fortunate to get a human birth. Amongst them, only a minuscule strive for spiritual perfection. And even among those perfected souls, ones who are aware of My divine glories and paramount position are very rare.”
> (Explanation Swami Mukundananda)

Comment: So you mean we can attain moksha even in sansar?

Comment: Moksha does not bear a cause and effect relationship with any Karma (though chitta shudhi - purity of mind is a benchmark. Any Karma is done to attain this chitta shudhi) . 
As Moksha is not a (direct) consequential, no scripture can ever say  that only if one is out of sansar , Moksha, is certain.